# SSD not recognized on Ubuntu though Windows sees it

Tags: windows, system-installation, ssd

I recently bought an Acer Nitro-5 and wanted to try Linux on it for the first time. I booted from a USB-Stick as usual, however the OS (Manjaro, Pop!, Ubuntu tried them all) did not recognize my SSD making installation impossible. I then proceeded to attempt to install windows on it, which then worked immediately. I would however like to install Linux in the long term and decided that before I call a technician I should ask here.

Laptop Specs:

- CPU:   Intel i5-9300J
- GPU:   RTX 2060
- RAM:   8Gb DDR4
- SSD:   Micron_2200_MTFDHBA512TCK

Comment: Typically need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. Similar Acers: Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969
 & [SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42

Answer (score 3):

Your SATA mode in your BIOS is set to (Intel) RST instead of AHCI. Enter your BIOS, press <kbd>Ctrl + s</kbd> in the main tab and change the mode to AHCI, then save the changes and exit.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!