# In UEFI Class 3 how install centos 8

Tags: centos, boot, ssd

I recently bought a sf514 ACER laptop. The BIOS of this laptop is UEFI Class 3, so it does not have AHCI mode. When I installed centos 8 it could not detect the nvme ssd hard drive, how do I install centos 8 ?

Comment: What does UEFI class 3 have to do with AHCI?  AHCI is the standard for SATA controllers. AHCI vs RAID mode  has to my knowledge nothing to do with (U)EFI and lack of Compatibility Support Module nor NVME drives since those are their own controller.

Comment: Please check this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613222) to change the SATA mode.

Comment: Many new Acer require Control-S when in UEFI to open more settings. Probably have to have UEFI Secure boot on to change settings also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your answer, I will try it  if the ACER laptop has ctrl+s hidden function keys, thank you very much.

Comment: My BOOT MODE shows UEFI and is gray.

Answer (score 2):

UEFI class 3 essentially means the system does not have a Compatibility Support Module (CSM) to provide legacy BIOS compatibility, so it boots in native UEFI mode only.

AHCI is the currently dominant hardware programming interface standard for SATA disk controllers. Your system may have no way to select "AHCI mode" in the firmware settings (used to be called "BIOS settings" but in UEFI Class 3 there is no BIOS), but that only means any SATA controllers will probably be in native AHCI mode always, instead of offering a legacy IDE-compatible mode. This is because an UEFI class 3 system has no BIOS compatibility support module, it cannot run legacy OSs that would require a BIOS and IDE compatibility. Since AHCI is older than UEFI, every OS that supports UEFI is expected to also support AHCI as a matter of course.

(Since a modern laptop is unlikely to have more than one SATA drive, RAID modes are probably not applicable either.)

With NVMe, AHCI is not applicable at all anyway, since the point of NVMe is that it removes the need for the HDD-oriented SATA interface and connects the SSD directly to the PCIe bus.

Make sure you are using [a fresh CentOS installation media/image](https://www.centos.org/download/) instead of some old version you might have had lying around: the new version may have been updated for improved support for new hardware.

If your particular laptop model (full model number is something like sf514-???) is newer than the current major release of the OS you're trying to install, you generally may have problems with hardware support, particularly if you're trying to run a stability-oriented Linux distribution like CentOS.

When you get to the point in the installer that indicates the hard drive is not detected, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to gain access to a root shell prompt. There you can perform diagnostics?

- Is the NVMe drive detected in the `lspci` output? (If the drive is working correctly, it should be detectable with `lspci` even without any drivers at all.)
- Is the `nvme` kernel module getting loaded? If not, try loading it with `modprobe nvme` command, and then return to the installer with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and retry the storage detection step.
- Is the `lsblk` command detecting the NVMe drive? It should appear as a `nvme0n1` device.
- Run `dmesg -H`, scroll through the entire list of kernel diagnostic messages and see if there are any messages about the NVMe drive and/or any problems accessing it.

Your system seems to have a NVMe drive *remapped* to AHCI. This mode is not supported by Linux so far, and the problem is, there seems to be no way to transition to a supported mode at runtime - the BIOS must do it. [Here's the relevant comment from the Linux kernel development Git repository:](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/ata?h=v5.9.1&id=aecec8b60422118b52e3347430ba9382e57d6d76)

> Some Intel ahci implementations have a completely broken remapping mode
> where they hide one or more NVMe devices behind the bar of an AHCI device.
>
> Intel refuses to let the OS reprogram the BIOS to switch out of this
> mode at runtime, and so far we're not come up with another good way
> to undo the mess that the Chipset people created.  So for now the only
> thing we can do is to alert users about this situation and switch to the
> faster and much saner so called "AHCI" mode insted of the RAID mode in
> the BIOS so that the BIOS does not hide the NVMe devices from us.
>
> The sitation is even worse as at least one vendor (thanks a lot Lenovo..)
> has started hardcoding their BIOS into the "RAID" mode even for laptops
> that don't use AHCI *at all* and just have a single NVMe device.  For now
> there is an unspported Linux-only BIOS that undoes this braindamage,
> but we'll have to see if things are getting better or worse from here.
>
> Based on an earlier patch from Dan Williams dan.j.williams@intel.com.

According to [this discussion on Acer support forums](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/582666/no-access-to-internal-ssd-when-outside-win10-on-an-acer-swift-5-sf514-54t), the BIOS setting that changes the storage controller mode should be named `Sata mode`, not `Boot mode`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I used the dmesg command and saw a few lines of information about nvme ssd. The message is as follows:
[5.804351] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 1 remapped NVMe devices.
[5.804351] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.
[5.804445] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 16 ports 3 Gbps 0x0 impl RAID mode
[5.804447] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst
This message seems to tell me to change the BIOS to AHCI mode, but my BOOT MODE it is grayed out and cannot be changed.

Comment: It looks like the NVMe device is *remapped* to the AHCI controller somehow. If there is an existing RAID configuration, there might be a safety check in the BIOS that prevents switching the controller mode while a valid RAID configuration exists. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Excuse me, is this a problem with the CentOS operating system or the laptop itself.

Comment: Please see my edit. Unfortunately it looks like there is no support for NVMe-remapped-to-AHCI so far (and the Linux developer in question calls that mode "braindamaged"), but the relevant BIOS setting should be called "SATA mode", not "BOOT mode".