# How do I disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology in order to install Linux Mint?

Tags: boot, grub2, storage, bios, intel

I have an Acer Predator Helios 300 with a 256GB SSD. It came with Windows 10 when I bought it, now I want to switch to Linux, because I'd like to learn how to work with it to better prepare for my graduate software engineer job which starts soon. And I heard it's just plain better than Windows, which I have many reasons to believe.

So I have put Linux Mint on a USB drive using the program Rufus. Then I managed to "boot into Linux" is the correct term I guess, and I saw an icon on the desktop called "Install Linux". I opened it, but during the setup, it said I need to disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology in order to install Linux.

No, I don't want to "dual boot" Windows and Linux, I don't want to have 2 operating systems at the same time, just Linux is all I want. I've read a number of articles, each with various clarity, explaining how to disable it in different ways from different places, but I read that if you don't do it right, it can actually break your computer.

I'm not experienced with BIOS settings, so I've been hesitant to touch anything there without guidance. I've heard various things, such as that I need to disable "Secure Boot" and what not. Everyone says different things.

I have tried one thing, which didn't eliminate the problem: I went to the "Uninstall a Program" feature of Windows and attempted to uninstall Intel Rapid Storage Technology, but the setup said something like:

*"Since Intel Rapid Storage Technology may be used to run your hard drive, it may not be uninstalled. Instead, you can uninstall non-critical parts, such as shortcuts."*

I proceeded, and after the uninstallation, I managed to boot into Linux from my flash drive again, but the same problem occurred when I opened the icon called Install Linux, it still told me I need to disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology before I can install Linux. I guess this "uninstallation" I performed didn't really do anything apart from deleting shortcuts.

Here is the most convincing set of steps to perform that I have stumbled across on the Acer Community website:

- Open a Command Prompt  window as admin.
- Set the boot loader to go to safe boot:
  bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
- Restart and get into the BIOS, switch the SATA operation mode from RST to AHCI (press ctrl+s in the
  main BIOS tab in order the option to appear), save changes and Windows goes into Safe Mode.
- Open the prompt again and remove the BCD value:
  bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
- Reboot and that's it.

Again, I've been hesitant to perform these because I don't know what they're doing and what the consequences could be and how to undo them if something goes wrong and my laptop breaks. Can somebody help please?

Please note: I have used Linux Mint before on a VirtualBox VM. The screen was so small though, like it didn't feel like the real deal, you know?

My laptop's info:

- Name: **Acer Predator Helios 300**
- Model Number: **M17C1**

Can somebody please help me disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology, without breaking my computer, so I can finally make the much-anticipated switch to Linux? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Try [unix.stackexchange.com/a/613232/332764](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613232/332764).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is going to "break" your computer. Setting the mode from RST to AHCI is perfectly fine. I've been using Linux on various laptops for many years and using AHCI is just a regular thing. I personally went through the same steps and found no issues. I didn't need `bcedit` though - pressing F2 at boot time was good enough for opening the BIOS for me. And the `CTRL-S` bit was indeed needed to show the SATA setting (to switch to AHCI).

Note however that switching the SATA mode will most likely destroy your Windows installation. In my case, I'm just happy to remove all and install Linux-only on the laptop. But there are tutorials out there that guide you into changing the Windows HAL so that the new AHCI setting is supported as well.

But in short, no danger. AHCI is not going to make your computer go on fire.

Comment: I believe you mean AHCI "Advanced Host Controller Interface", not ACHI. A permanent change is what is needed.